# UPDATE operation takes 6 seconds

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

I do an `UPDATE` request from my client app to the database (SQL Server 2008 R2), and it takes 6 seconds to complete.

Currently I have around 5 millions rows in that table.

Here is the query:

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET subject2 = 'information abx', dateProcessed = '2012-02-27 23:02:44' 
WHERE id = 3712028;
```

Where columns are:

```
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[dateProcessed] [datetime] NULL,
[subject2] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
```

Any ways to defragment database of something like that?? :)

I don't think that 6 seconds is normal time to update 1 row searching by indexed field...

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks,

UPDATE 1: I'm sorry guys! I don't have indexes in the table. I thought IDENTITY is someth like INDEX also. So probably I should add INDEX to id field or make it PRIMARY KEY

Comment: do you have any indexes or triggers?

Comment: Have you had a look at the Include Actual Execution Plan option in SSMS? That should give you an idea of why your query is so slow.

Comment: +1.  Whenever you have a performance issue, checking the QEP should be your first step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaring a column `identity` does not automatically makes it indexed; declaring it a *primary key* does:

```
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
```

You can add the constraint to an existing database like this:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

Comment: I think the odds are strong that this is the issue. I can't see updating an index as being that slow.

Comment: @ChaosPandion I agree, consistently spending six seconds on a single-row update is a sure sign of a full-table scan.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an index defined on the subject2 or dateProcessed columns then your update could be slow due to the indexes being updated.

If you do, it may be worth dropping them if you don't query on these fields frequently.

It's also worth making the ID field a primary key if feasable, which will give it an index and speed up lookups.